# InlineCssTextArea (RichTextFX) current style?

Tags: javafx, richtextfx

I'm trying to achieve something like rich text editor in javafx, using RichTextFX library component: InlineCssTextArea.

I've expect an API similar to this:

```
InlineCssTextArea area = new InlineCssTextArea();
area.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
//now user input is bold
area.setStyle("text-decoration: underline;");
//now user input is bold and underlined
area.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: normal;");
//now user input is just underlined
```

But it seems, that all style changes has to be applied to a range of characters. Did I miss something? This use case seems to be the most natural one.

Do I have to track current carret position, and apply changes accordingly?

Comment: See official [RichText Editor demo](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX#rich-text-editor)